# How to create documents in the api but with place of signature

Tags: docusignapi

I need create documents from my software to api integration but I would like of mark the place of signature for client.

Its possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, easy-peasy. When creating the DocuSign envelope, include a `sign here tab` with the create call. And use anchor text to tell DocuSign where the signature request should appear.

[Here is the recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/autoplace). And here is example software that [you can run on Heroku for free](https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/DocuSign/recipe-012-multiple-docs-python).

Note: in order to run the recipe on Heroku, [you'll need a free developer account on DocuSign, plus a free integration key.](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#quickstart)

Answer (score 1):

When creating envelopes in the DocuSign system there are generally three different methods for placing signature and other tabs.

1. Absolute (or fixed) positioning.
2. Relative positioning (aka Anchor Tags or Auto-Place).
3. PDF Form fields.

(1): With absolute positioning you can set the (x,y) coordinates of where you want to place tabs through your documents.  You can set that manually by dragging and dropping through the DocuSign Website, or you can set those locations through the API. See Larry's API Recipes links.

(2): The anchor tagging (aka Auto-place) feature places tabs in your documents based on the actual document content itself. For instance, you can place a signature tab anywhere the text `"Please Sign Here"` is found in your document(s).  However please note that it will place a signature tab for each and every instance of that string it finds, not just the first.

(3): The third option for placing tabs only work with non-flattened PDF files. If you have a PDF with form fields in it, DocuSign can read those fields and locations and place tabs there. This is easy and powerful, but of course only works with PDF files.

Learn more about all these option at the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center).

Answer (score 0):

What I've found is that it will place a signature tab for every document in an envelope, even if the other documents are using a different server template.